# ggplotly no me grafica el mismo grafico que ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, visualización-de-datos

Estoy intentando hacer un gráfico interactivo usando la funcion ggplot**ly**. El resultado no es lo que espero porque no se muestra el mismo grafico.

Mi data es:
[image: Image of my Data]
La modifico en 3 columnas (X1, X2, value) para que sea apropiada para ser graficada con ggplot usando el codigo:

`reshapeddata = melt(heatmapdata)`

El codigo para plotear es:

```
heatmap1 = ggplot(reshapeddata, aes(X1, X2))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=value),
            color = "white",
            lwd = 1,
            linetype = 1) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(limits=c(0, 600),
                       colors = c("red","yellow","white")) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12))+
  labs(title=paste(" \n \n Heatmap Events \n\n"), y = "", x = "")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "italic")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 1)))+
  coord_flip()+
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  geom_tile(data = filter(reshapedPDCs, value > 600), 
            mapping = aes(fill = value > 600))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = "white") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 1)))
```

Y cuando ploteo *heatmap1* obtengo el gráfico que quiero:
[image: Heatmap1]

El problema está cuando intento convertirlo a gráfico interactivo usando ggplotly con: `heatmap2 = ggplotly(heatmap1)` . Obtengo un gráfico muy erroneo:

[image: Wrong heatmap]
Me tira el siguiente error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In geom2trace.default(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]], dots[[3L]][[1L]]) :
  geom_NewGeomTile() has yet to be implemented in plotly.
  If you'd like to see this geom implemented,
  Please open an issue with your example code at
  https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues
2: In geom2trace.default(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]], dots[[3L]][[1L]]) :
  geom_NewGeomText() has yet to be implemented in plotly.
  If you'd like to see this geom implemented,
  Please open an issue with your example code at
  https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues
```

Como puedo hacer para que el segundo gráfico *heatmap2* se parezca al primero *heatmap1*?

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Hay partes de ese ggplot que ya son [issues reportados](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/2116) a abril de 2022, como te lo indica el log que nos muestras.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de plotly estás usando? `packageVersion("plotly")`

Comment: Estoy usando 4.10.0 @PatricioMoracho

Answer (score 0):

El tema que más perplejo me dejaba, es que las geometrías `tile` y `text` son bien básicas y soportadas por `plotly` desde siempre. Finalmente el problema lo tienes con el paquete [`ggnewscale`](https://github.com/eliocamp/ggnewscale) de Elio Campitelli, que redefine los `geoms` clásicos en nuevos objetos con el nombre `geom_New*`, los cuales obviamente no están soportados por `plotly`  Técnicamente se puede decir que ambos paquetes son incompatibles entre si y no podrías usar  [`ggnewscale`](https://github.com/eliocamp/ggnewscale) si piensas integrarlo a `plotly`.

Comment: Gracias Patricio por tu respuesta. El motivo por el cual usé ggnewscale, es porque necesito que todos los valores menores a X se grafiquen de acuerdo a la escala y que los mayores a X queden en blanco. X en el ejemplo es 600, pero en realidad es una variable que depende de los datos. Tenes idea de cómo puedo resolver esto sin usar ggnewscale para poder usar plotly?

Comment: Por lo que comentas, me parece que no necesitas 2 escalas sino una sola con cierto gradiente de color. Yo te sugiero que vayas un paso atrás, y plantees el problema real y no la solución que intentaste. Hacé una pregunta nueva, agregale un ejemplo de los datos (la salida `dput(reshapeddata)` la copias a la misma pregunta) y plantea lo que que buscas, por ejemplo "quiero hacer un mapa de calor, con cierta escala de colores pero quiero que lo valores inferiores a X aparezcan en color blanco".

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio! Voy a intentar hacerlo!!

Comment: Con la solución sin ggnewscale debería funcionar https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/527455/126758

Comment: @dieghernan, esta muy buena tu respuesta, aunque es una respuesta a una pregunta que todavía no formuló Maria, te dejó como sugerencia lo que suelo hacer en estos casos, es decir, cuando interpreto entre líneas dónde está realmente el problema, formulo una nueva pregunta y la autorespondo, luego le dejó un comentario al usuario original para que la verifique, de esta forma pregunta y respuesta quedan consistentes. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho , como me sugeriste creé una nueva pregunta que potencialmente podría responder mis otras dos preguntas. Te paso el link por si queres seguirla https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/527514/c%c3%b3mo-determinar-el-color-de-las-celdas-de-valores-mayores-que-la-escala-en-mi-h gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Hola @dieghernan , como mencioné en el comentario anterio (no te pude etiquetar) formulé una nueva pregunta que podría solucionar mis otras dos preguntas. Aqui esta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/527514/c%c3%b3mo-determinar-el-color-de-las-celdas-de-valores-mayores-que-la-escala-en-mi-h Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Bárbaro Maria, ahí @dieghernan podría copiarte la respuesta que ya te dió en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/527514/c%c3%b3mo-determinar-el-color-de-las-celdas-de-valores-mayores-que-la-escala-en-mi-h