# ¿Como puedo eliminar la leyenda de mi heatmap en R?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2, visualización-de-datos

Me gustaría eliminar la leyenda "Events > 600: TRUE" de la figura y no se cómo hacerlo...

[image: Mi heatmap con leyenda erronea]

El código para graficar es:

```html
reshapeddata = melt(events_heatmap)
names(reshapeddata)[3] <- 'Events'

heatmap = ggplot(reshapeddata, aes(X2, X1))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=Events),
            color = "white",
            lwd = 1,
            linetype = 1) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(limits=c(0, 600),
                colors = c("red","yellow","white")) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev, expand = c(0, 0)) + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12))+
  labs(title=paste("Heatmap Events"), y = "", x = "")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "italic")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(Events, 1)))+
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  geom_tile(data = filter(reshapeddata, Events > 600),
            mapping = aes(fill = Events > 600)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "white")+
  geom_text(aes(label = round(Events, 1)))
```

La línea causante del problema es esta:
mapping = aes(fill = Events > 600)), dentro de la nueva escala.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: María, normalmente quitar una leyenda se puede hacer agregando `+ theme(legend.position="none")` sin embargo como te dije en tu otra pregunta, creo que estás enfocando el problema en la solución y no en el requerimiento inicial, el mapa de calor.

Comment: Gracias Patricio! Hace muy poco empecé con R, este es mi primer script! Por lo que es muy valioso tu comentario. Gracias por la ayuda!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puedes simplificar tu código sin usar `ggnewscale`. En `scale_fill_gradientn` ya estás definiendo la escala, para aquellos valores fuera de los límites `0-600` puedes controlar el color con el parámetro `na.value`.

Como no has proporcionado un dataset de ejemplo, he tenido que crear uno de manera artificial, espero que aun así el ejemplo se entienda bien:

```r
# Creo unos datos de ejemplo

set.seed(1234)
events_heatmap <- matrix(sample(1:900, 96), ncol = 12)
events_heatmap <- as.data.frame(events_heatmap)
colnames(events_heatmap) <- as.character(1:12)

events_heatmap <- cbind(id = LETTERS[1:8], events_heatmap)
events_heatmap
#>   id   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
#> 1  A 284 726 574 605 108 811 307 145 297 643 276  60
#> 2  B 848 602   4 634 131 258 855 123 208 595 169 449
#> 3  C 101 326 661 578 343 629 221 776 867 434  71 548
#> 4  D 623  79 552 510  41 889 736 234 569 757 573  19
#> 5  E 645 884 212 687 627 182 561 608 522 760 890 649
#> 6  F 400 270 195 424 740 305 313 495 248 218 485 638
#> 7  G  98 382 511 379 840 358 136 534 365 727 667 670
#> 8  H 103 184 479 816 298 696 794 803 665 508 460 319

reshapeddata <- reshape2::melt(events_heatmap)
#> Using id as id variables
names(reshapeddata) <- c("X1", "X2", "Events")
reshapeddata$X2 <- as.integer(reshapeddata$X2)


# Creados

library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.1.1

heatmap <- ggplot(reshapeddata, aes(X2, X1)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Events),
    color = "white",
    lwd = 1,
    linetype = 1
  ) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    limits = c(0, 600),
    colors = c("red", "yellow", "white"),
    # Controla el valor de los NAs, aquellos fuera de tus limites
    na.value = "white"
  ) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev, expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)) +
  labs(title = paste("Heatmap Events"), y = "", x = "") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "italic")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(Events, 1)))

heatmap
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>